# Connecting 3 or more different php files with each other (Include/Require functions)

Tags: php

I have a problem like this before but I solved it the indecent way (copy pasting codes of one file to other which makes it redundant). I got several files included/required to other files (example, classes/class1.php, classes/class2.php and models/session.php) but I got an error when I include two files saying something about include. I know my explanation is bad but I somehow understand that it involves the path of the files. My guess are the ____DIR____ and ____FILE____ functions but I don't know how to use them. Can somebody help me?

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: I...I lost the file when my mate accidentally deleted the "problem" file set and the recovered ones don't have the error.

Comment: So your problem is you dont understand how to use __DIR__ and __FILE__ constants?

Comment: Well, if we're going to go directly to what I want since it would solve the past problem I had.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please, could you provide some code of your specific problem. That prove how far did you try and it will help other members to understand your problem better, at the time, you will give them a context of your issue. Please, check these links: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask